# What is this strange spontaneous Facebook/Google Chrome popup?

Tags: google-chrome

Recently my Ubuntu 12.10 system has started the following strange behavior:  A Google Chrome window will pop up, trying to load this URL:

> http://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=302061903208115&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26display%3Dpopup%26scope%3Dpublish_stream%252Cread_stream%252Cstatus_update%252Cuser_photos%252Cfriends_photos%252Cxmpp_login%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D302061903208115%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=popup

This will result in a page that says:

> Success 
>   SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.

With URL:

> =">https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#*=*

(Despite that warning, I don't seen anything confidential in the URL.)

What I find very strange about this is that it will pop up a few minutes after I boot my system, *before I even start Chrome*.

Is this some kind of malware, or what?

EDIT: After deleting the "Ubuntu App" from Facebook(!), the popups still occur, but now they bring up a message saying "Ubuntu would like to access your public profile, friend list, News Feed, photos and your friends' photos."

Comment: Even I am having the same issue, since a few hours back. I didn't upgrade anything, all I did today was install lisp, no upgrades nothing. I wonder how can something be changed when I have not upgraded anything.

Comment: This is a known bug. I don't have the link to hand, but if I find it I will post it.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the solution was to remove my Facebook account from the Ubuntu settings.  Why do I want Ubuntu to know about my Facebook account anyway?

```
System Settings -> Online Accounts --> Facebook --> Remove Account
```

Comment: I removed it, and the problem seems to have gone away

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of the account manager used by Gwibber, related to some changes in the login mechanism of Facebook. You should consider upgrading your system, the last version of Ubuntu is 13.04.

Comment: I removed Gwibber (`apt-get remove gwibber`) yet the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the answer was not very clear... It's not Gwibber by itself, but the account manager used by Gwibber. If you want to keep your Facebook details in Ubuntu you must upgrade the system, otherwise you will keep getting that bug. 13.04 has been out for more than 1 month now, why waiting anyways? :)

Comment: This problem exists on 13.04 as well, so it can't just be about upgrading. Something else is causing it...

Comment: I'm using 13.04 right now and I don't have those problems. There are still problems with the account manager, but NOT the browser randomly starting, so I think those are two separate issues, not the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

System Settings -> On line Accounts -> delete the entry for facebook